# Xamarin.Android HTTP Random Delays

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, threadpool, dotnet-httpclient

I have a method that executes several HTTP requests called `LoadServers()` A button that executes `LoadServers()`. For my issue I only tap the button once the previous `LoadServers()` call has finished. A progress dialog appears while loading so I can only execute them serially.

Once in about every 10-15 calls to `LoadServers` results in the first http request to delay for almost exactly 10 seconds. The average time for `LoadServers` to complete is less than a half second and never more than 1 second. This only happens on Xamarin.Android. The delay does not happen on Xamarin.iOS and all of this code is shared.

Here is my code

```
private async Task LoadServers() {
    await Get();
    await Post();
    await Get();
    await Get();
    await Post();
}

private async Task Get() {
    var url = _httpClient.BaseAddress + model.GetToken();
    Log("Attempting to send GET to: " + url);
    using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
    {
        var resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Log("Got response back from : " + url + ": " + resultContent);
    }
}

private async Task Post() {
    var content = requestData.GetToken() + "=" + requestData.PostBody ();
    var request = new StringContent(content)
    {
        Headers = { ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") }
    };
    var url = _httpClient.BaseAddress + "/No_content";
    Log ("Attempting to send POST to: " + url + "  with content: " + content);
    using (var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, request))
    {
        string resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Log("Got response back from : " + url + ": " + resultContent);
    }
}
```

Every 15 or so executions of `LoadServers()` results in the following log statements:

```
Thread started:  #37
Thread finished:  #37
[2017-01-21T13:42:30.8841620-06:00] [debug] Loading Servers
[2017-01-21T13:42:30.8946770-06:00] [debug] Attempting to send GET to: XXX
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #23
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #38
[2017-01-21T13:42:40.9550360-06:00] [debug] Got response back from : XXX <-- Notice the time (~10 seconds)
```

Does this have to do with resource consumption for the HTTP request? It attempts to clean up the resources and pauses execution until that happens? I'm not sure exactly what happens when it execute the request. Does it start a new thread?

Comment: I cant reproduce your issue, but I found two problems with your code. 1. since you're doing thread work in your `Get()` and `Post()` methods using key word `await`, then these two methods should be `async`. 2. these two methods are not tasks and they are void, you don't need/can't  `await` them in your task `LoadServers`. I don't know how you make your code run, by my side, I need to modify your code but still I couldn't reproduce your issue. To isolate device problem, you can use emulator or other android device to test your code.

Comment: Hi @GraceFeng-MSFT, Thanks for the response. As I was cleaning up the code, I accidentally put those as void's instead of `Task`'s. I edited the question. This is over a local network and connecting to a local device. So the time it usually takes the device to respond is 10-30 milliseconds. This happens on many different devices and many different Android OS API levels. Since it doesn't happen on iOS with the exact same code, I'm thinking its something with Android.

Comment: @kevskree, try running the same code in a console application on your Mac to remove the mobile SDKs from the equation. Next, file an issue over at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Android with the sample we can use to try and reproduce. You can include a sample as a private attachment. Include any details we might need to set this up locally.

Comment: @therealjohn Thanks for the suggestion. I was just able to make a sample with a console app vs an Android app. I wasn't able to reproduce it on the console app and the delay still did occur on Android. I'll be writing up a bug in bugzilla. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Figuring out the exact issue is tough, and I'm unable to reproduce it. However, the wrapping of `System.Net` and the default MessageHandler in the `HttpClient` is not completely optimized. So, your guess at it being a resource issue could be the case.

Try using ModernHttpClient ([Xamarin Component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient) | [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient/) | [Developer Review](https://alexdunn.org/2016/06/17/xamarin-component-review-modernhttpclient/) | [Github](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient)), and adding the `NativeMessageHandler` in the constructor for you `HttpClient`. This will use the some optimized native libraries (for Android, it's `OkHttp`) which will help with performance.

Comment: Haven't they essentially built ModernHttpClient into the latest version of Xamarin.Android ?

Comment: They've increased it's performance, but `OkHttp` takes it a step further. Also, that would only be when calling it from the Xamarin.Android project's code, not from a PCL. The PCL will use the built in .NET Portable HttpClient which doesn't use the new handler.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented the same issue.
i'm using xamarin.android 6.6.1.2-21 and support stuff for Api 23.

I found that using the *default httpHandler* and creating 2 httpClients before your first call solve this issue.

```
new HttpClient( new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler());
```

and create 2 httpclients before start any real call in your code.

Also setup the "HttpClient implementation" to "AndroidClientHandler". You can find this option on: Project options > Android build > Code generation And Runtime.
This only work on android 5+

[http implementation option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EvDF.png)

Comment: You mean simply calling 
    ```var client = new HttpClient(new     Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler());
    client = new HttpClient(new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler());```

fixes the issue?

Comment: format your codes. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Yep. Create two httpclient before create the httpClient that you will use to make `getAsync()` or `postAsync()`.

Also setup the "HttpClient implementation" to "AndroidClientHandler". You can find this option on Project options> Android build >Code generation And Runtime.

Comment: Unfortunately, using the Android Client Handler in code or project settings causes my HTTP requests to execute extremely slow. Normally requests take < 50 milliseconds and with the Android client it takes appx. 5-10 seconds per request. I'm really not sure why but still debugging.

Comment: that's really odd. It supposed to be faster.
are you creating the httpclient from Android or from a PCL?

Comment: I am creating the client in the Android app and have a simple Get and Post interface that I pass down to the PCL. I'm befuddled on why it makes it slower

Comment: I'm creating the httpClient on (.Droid) on android. 
Then i use the DependencyService to pass the httpclient object to PCL.